# How to properly make one figure child on another in Draw2D Touch

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

I'm using [Draw2D](http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/) to render diagram. I'm rendering parent rectangles and child rectangles:

```
var parent = new draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle(90, 30);

var child1 = new draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle(30, 30);
var child2 = new draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle(30, 30);
var child3 = new draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle(30, 30);

parent.addFigure(child1, new draw2d.layout.locator.CenterLocator(parent));
parent.addFigure(child2, new draw2d.layout.locator.CenterLocator(parent));
parent.addFigure(child3, new draw2d.layout.locator.CenterLocator(parent));
```

However, according to [the documentation](http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/#!/api/draw2d.Figure-method-addFigure),

> Add a child figure to the figure. The hands over figure doesn't
>   support drag&drop operations. It's only a decorator for the
>   connection. Mainly for labels or other fancy decorations :-)

Besides, `Figure` object has no methods `insertFigure` and `removeFigure`.

How to properly wrap one figure by another in Draw2D?

Comment: Can you please clearify you question. What do you want to do? Put the three children side by side to they all fit in the parent?

Comment: No, it's not about positioning. It's about creating and manipulating of children. I was wanted simple to add child element or insert it after another child element, then remove. As I understood, these basic function are not available for now.

Comment: addFigure(figure, locator) does it - so where is the problem. I am experimenting a lot with 2d theses days - so if you clearify you question I may help.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, but I already switched to GoJS (low SVG performance on initial loading, insufficient functionality and lack of support were the cause). Problem is that you have no methods to insert child in some position, remove child, change its position among another children. I implemented these functions by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, I should use `draw2d.shape.layout.VerticalLayout` or `draw2d.shape.layout.HorizontalLayout` to unite figures, but these classes still have no methods for inserting or deleting child nodes.